# How to insert a scale on a map in R

Tags: r, terra

I would like to know if it is possible to generate an equal scale of the attached image, highlighted in red

```
library(terra)
library(geodata)
brz <- geodata::gadm("Brazil", level=2, path=".")
mun <- brz[brz$NAME_2 == "Castro", ]
plot(mun, main="", axes=FALSE)
```

[image]

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tm_scale_bar` from the `tmap` package to add the scale bar to a map. Additionally, you might need `sf` to convert `mun` from `SpatVector` to `sf` (a format usable by tmap).

```
library(tmap)
library(sf)

# Transform mun to sf
tm_shape(sf::st_as_sf(mun)) +
  # Draw as polygon with only borders
  tm_borders() +
  # Add scale bar
  tm_scale_bar(position = c("LEFT", "BOTTOM"))
```

[image: map]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I would also like to insert along with the scale that image above
from the scale, as shown in the attached figure, is it possible?

Comment: Yeah, you can use `tm_compass`

Comment: Thanks for reply! Please, can you help me insert it along with the scale you created to match the attached image?

Comment: Just add `+ tm_compass()` at the end of the previous code

Answer (score 1):

Another option is using the libraries `ggspatial` and `tidyterra`.

```
library(ggspatial)
library(tidyterra)

ggplot() +
  geom_spatvector(data = mun)  +
  annotation_scale() + # add scale
  annotation_north_arrow(location = "br", which_north = "true") + # add arrow
  theme(
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y=element_blank(),  #remove y axis labels
    axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),  #remove y axis ticks
    axis.text.x=element_blank(),  #remove x axis labels
    axis.ticks.x=element_blank()  #remove x axis ticks
  )
```

[image]